# webpack init trying to use unsupported extract-text-webpack-plugin

Tags: webpack, asp.net-core, yarnpkg, extracttextwebpackplugin

When creating a fresh web project using ASP.NET Core and Webpack, I'm getting dependency warnings from yarn about `extract-text-webpack-plugin`.

---

My steps to reproduce:

1. `dotnew new web`
2. `yarn init`
3. `yarn add --dev webpack webpack-cli`
4. `webpack init`

*The following warning message is displayed:*

> warning " > extract-text-webpack-plugin@3.0.2" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@^3.1.0".

5. `webpack`

*Displays the following error message:*

> (node:19320) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new
>   API on '.hooks' instead
>   D:\SRC\MISC\WebpackTest\node_modules\webpack\lib\Chunk.js:460
>                   throw new Error(
>                   ^
>
> Error: Chunk.entrypoints: Use Chunks.groupsIterable and filter by
>   instanceof Entrypoint instead
>       at Chunk.get (D:\SRC\MISC\WebpackTest\node_modules\webpack\lib\Chunk.js:460:9)
>       at D:\SRC\MISC\WebpackTest\node_modules\extract-text-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:176:48
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at D:\SRC\MISC\WebpackTest\node_modules\extract-text-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:171:18
>       at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (D:\SRC\MISC\WebpackTest\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:24:12),
>   :7:1)
>       at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook [as _callAsync] (D:\SRC\MISC\WebpackTest\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:35:21)
>       at Compilation.seal (D:\SRC\MISC\WebpackTest\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:881:27)
>       at hooks.make.callAsync.err (D:\SRC\MISC\WebpackTest\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:464:17)
>       at _err0 (eval at create (D:\SRC\MISC\WebpackTest\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:24:12),
>   :11:1)
>       at _addModuleChain (D:\SRC\MISC\WebpackTest\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:749:12)
>       at processModuleDependencies.err (D:\SRC\MISC\WebpackTest\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:688:9)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:150:11)

---

The current versions of webpack yarn is pulling down are:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "webpack": "^4.1.1",
  "webpack-cli": "^2.0.10"
},
```

I'm aware that `extract-text-webpack-plugin` does not yet support Webpack 4 so I'm curious why the `webpack init` tries to include it. Are there any alternatives to `extract-text-webpack-plugin` or is the only workaround to roll back to Webpack 3?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After raising [an issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/issues/320) with `webpack-cli` this bad reference has been addressed in this [pull request](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/pull/323).

The fix has updated the package dependency to `extract-text-webpack-plugin@next` and having tested this locally I can confirm that this no longer throws an error on build.

```
yarn remove extract-text-webpack-plugin
yarn add --dev extract-text-webpack-plugin@next
```

Answer (score 3):

I have faced same problem using `npm`, it is solved similarly to the yarn solution:

```
npm uninstall extract-text-webpack-plugin
npm i -D extract-text-webpack-plugin@next
```

[Ref](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/701#issuecomment-368475240)

Altough authors state:

> ⚠️ Since webpack v4 the extract-text-webpack-plugin should not be used for css. Use mini-css-extract-plugin instead.

[Ref](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin)

Answer (score 1):

You can use mini-css-extract-plugin, which is I believe supposed to replace extract-text-webpack-plugin for webpack 4.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mini-css-extract-plugin

But beware of some issues like broken incremental css rebuilds in watch mode, as it is only a beta release for now.

Comment: While this plugin may suffice for simpler builds, it does not have feature parity with extract-text-webpack-plugin unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a question of installing extract-text-webpack-plugin when your environment is in webpack 4,you just need do as follows:

```
npm i extract-text-webpack-plugin@next -D
```

but i also have a question: the version 4 of extract-text-webpack-plugin is completed three years ago, why i execute extract-text-webpack-plugin@4.0.0 which is error?